# How to output series file name to folder name without seasons number

Tags: ffmpeg

just i want to make out put like example using for f

i have series episode
`Fast Fast S01E02.mkv`
i want output to directory /media/**Fast Fast**/Fast Fast S01E02.mkv

how i can equivalent folder name from file name without S01E02

i use this

`for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=40:main_h-overlay_h-40" -codec:a aac -c:v h264 /media/folder name/"${f%.*}".mkv`

`for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=40:main_h-overlay_h-40" -codec:a aac -c:v h264 /media/folder name/"${f%.*}".mkv`

Comment: maybe, this way `... "/media/${f% *}/${f%.*}.mkv"`

Comment: how i can only get seasons number and episode only from file name for example "Fast Fast - S01E02.mkv" i need only "S01E02"

Comment: two step: `t=${f%.*}; echo ${t##* }`